# JQuery Datatable with 50% width

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I have the following datatable getting data from ajax and I have not found a option to make its width 50%, is there any way to do this?

```
                    <div id="masonry" class="yesPrint">
                        <table class="table table-nonfluid table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_2">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="centralize" colspan="2">1 - Ramais</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr align="left">
                                <th>Número</th>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something...

You want to use a css style: `width: 50%;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KzXw/3/

Try wrapping it in a container and setting width: 50% on the container if you can't set it directly on the table. Like so:

```
#masonry { width: 50%; }
```